# Delphi 11.3, iOS: Managing application settings

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

Is it possible to manage iOS application settings using Delphi?

Different applications have a different set of default user settings on the phone.

For example:

[image]
[image]

I'm interested in these settings

1. How are these presets formed?
   How can I configure my own set of settings for my iOS application?
2. In particular, how can I configure a set for my application so that when the notification mode is turned on
   The "Banner" option was disabled and unavailable, or at least disabled?

Default:                                                       I need to disable the banner:

[image: Default]                   [image: I need to disable the banner]